# Progress bar doesn't animate during the entire loading process

Tags: c#, xaml, progress-bar

I have developed a small project that incorporates the functionality to execute an APL report (Ewic).

In addition, I have implemented a Progress bar to provide visual feedback to the user while running the report. Since the report typically involves loading tons of data.

I wanted the Progress bar to continuously move during the entire process. However, I encountered an issue where the Progress bar freezes as soon as the data loading starts, approximately 2-3 seconds after the user clicks the button.

Could you assist me in resolving this problem, so that the Progress bar moves continuously throughout the entire process?

here is my code

XAML containing the progress bar

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" Background="White">
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <ProgressBar x:Name="ProgressBar" Width="200" IsIndeterminate="True" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Loading... Please wait..." HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

XAML code containing the APL button

```
       
  
    <Grid>
        <Border BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="#FFBFE0DC" BorderThickness="1" Margin="50,20,50,30">
            <Grid>
            <Button x:Name="batchclose" Content="Close Batch" Cursor="Hand" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="45,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140" Height="50" Style="{StaticResource CustomButtonStyle}" Click="batchclose_Click" />
            <Button x:Name="runreport" Content="Transaction Report" Cursor="Hand" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,20,45,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140" Height="50" Style="{StaticResource CustomButtonStyle}" Click="runreport_Click" />
                <Button x:Name="aplreport" Content="Apl Report" Cursor="Hand" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="45,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140" Height="50" Style="{StaticResource CustomButtonStyle}" Click="aplreport_Click" />
                
            </Grid>
        </Border>
```

c# code containing the logic

```
private async void aplreport_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string api = MainWindow.Instance.ApiKey.Text;

                LoadingWindow loadingWindow = new LoadingWindow();
                loadingWindow.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                


                // Create an instance of HttpClient
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    // Set the base URL
                    string baseUrl = "URL";

                    // Create the request body
                    var requestBody = new
                    {
                        xKey = api,
                        xCommand = "report:ebtwapl",
                        xEbtwState = "MD",
                        xSoftwareName = "test",
                        xSoftwareVersion = "1",
                        xVersion = "5.0.0"
                    };

                   
                    string requestBodyJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestBody);

                   
                    HttpContent content = new StringContent(requestBodyJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                    // Send the POST request and retrieve the response
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(baseUrl, content);
                    

                   
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                        
                        var responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(responseContent);

                        // Get the report data from the response
                        var reportData = responseObject.xReportData;
                        


                        // Create a new window to display the response content
                        Window responseWindow = new Window();
                        responseWindow.Title = "API Response";
                        responseWindow.Width = 800;
                        responseWindow.Height = 600;

                        TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
                        textBox.IsReadOnly = true;
                        textBox.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
                        textBox.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;

                        textBox.Style = CreateTextBoxStyle();
                        responseWindow.Content = textBox;

                        responseWindow.Loaded += (responseWindowSender, responseWindowArgs) =>
                        {

                            // Close the loading window when the response window is loaded
                            loadingWindow.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                        };

                      
                       
                        foreach (var item in reportData)
                        {
                            // Get the URL from the report item
                            string url = item.URL;
                            if (item.Type == "Products")
                            {
                                
                                HttpResponseMessage urlResponse = await client.GetAsync(url);
                                string urlContent = await urlResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                               
                                
                                    textBox.AppendText("URL: " + url + Environment.NewLine);
                                    textBox.AppendText("URL Content:" + Environment.NewLine);
                                    textBox.AppendText(urlContent + Environment.NewLine);
                                    textBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);

                                
                               
                               
                            }
                        }
                        // Stop the progress bar animation
                       


                        responseWindow.ShowDialog();

                        // Hide the loading window
                        loadingWindow.Hide();




                    }
                    else
                    {
                        
                        Console.WriteLine("Request was not successful. Status code: " + response.StatusCode);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + ex.Message);
            }


        }
```

please, if anyone can help fix the issue